# What food source did the Fae use before humans?

Tags: lost-girl

The opening blurb of *Lost Girl* says that the Fae are "an evolutionary branch that predate humans". In episode 202 (i.e. 2nd episode of 2nd season), the other tree-named-head-honcho-Fae-person (sorry, my shoddy memory for names extends to TV shows) says something to the effect that "humans are food, sorry, but that's all there is to it". OK, that's all well and nice, but what did all those Fae use as their food source while they were patiently waiting for humans to evolve?

Comment: I'm guessing apes.

Comment: Hehe. And predate also means "to hunt".  Fun with English!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are misinterpreting what the Blackthorn means. He does not say "humans are the only type of food." It's as if I were to say "cows are food." That doesn't mean chickens, beans, and mushrooms aren't food.

Fae can also get nutrients from each other, and from other animals. There is nothing specific about humans; those Fae that need to consume life force can get it from lots of places.

Comment: I have at least one friend who would assert (vehemently) that mushrooms are indeed not food. :) I vaguely remember someone (may not have been the Blackthorn) saying that humans are the *best* food, though. Which kind of goes against evolutionary principles... :/

Comment: @Martha:  I completely agree with your friend:  mushrooms are NOT food.  :-D  They are fungi.  Blech.  I've never been able to get past that.

Comment: @MegCoates, well *I* think fungi are delicious, but then I like rotten moldy milk, too. (Otherwise known as blue cheese. Mmmm... cheese... now I'm hungry.)

Comment: @Martha Pies are the best food, but they didn't exist before humans. There's all sorts of examples of species that aren't the best in their native environments for whatever reason, but flourish in a different environment.

Answer (score 3):

I am pretty sure, after listening to this repeatedly, that you are mis-hearing the introduction. Note that almost everyone seems to make this mistake, as I did initially, but Lauren *is not saying* that fae have been around since before humans existed.

What Lauren actually says is:

> an evolutionary branch that predates *on* humans.

Lauren is using the correct biological terminology for the predator/prey relationship, but she is basically saying "they kill and eat people."

They implication here, though I don't think they've ever been quite so explicit about it, is that fae either evolved *from* humans, or evolved *in parallel with* humans from some common ancestor. Their ability to feed on humans evolved from the fact that so many humans existed to be food.

Comment: Except that the verb form of "predator" is *prey [on]*. A few dictionaries do allow for "predate" as a synonym of "prey", but in that case, the pronunciation is different. The show intro very clearly uses the long-e pronunciation that can only be *pre+date*, not *predator-or+e*.

Comment: except that I'm 99% sure she's stressing the second syllable, so the first 'e' can't be long. She's saying "pruh-DATES", not "PRE-dates". I'll have to check when the show comes back on-air around here. Plus, she says "predates **on**" which makes no sense using the other definition.

Comment: I don't remember ever hearing an "on" in there.